# all my post request give me "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." error in my shared hosting laravel 5.6

Tags: shared-hosting, laravel-5.6

all my post request give me "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." error  in my shared hosting but in local environment it work !!

Answer (score 0):

I added ob_start(); at the top of my index.php on server and everything seems to be working fine.